# Calling a constructor not filling textbox fields of already opened form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing an application where i have to get data from 2 different forms to fill different fields of same form

**My Work**

I have called the constructor of form1 from party form and from itemform with parameters
 code form Itemform

```
            string units = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string rate = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            Form1 f1 = new Form1( units, rate);

            this.Hide();
```

constructor on form1 called while debugging

```
    public Form1(string units, string rate)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         ItemId_LBL.Text = units;
         ItemName_TXT.Text = rate;
         }
```

same for another form but i no want to close my main form1 and only close other forms while clicking button constructor called but fields not populated **why**

**NOTE:**

> I HAVE TO FILL TEXTBOXES OF ALREADY OPENED FORM FORM1

Comment: you need a reference to the already opened Form1.
You create a new Form1 object, set some properties on it, but that does not affect the already existing instance

Comment: how to use existing object created of open form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from another form get object of opened form

```
    Form1 f = (Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1);

                f.PName_TXT.Text = name.ToString();
                f.PId_LBL.Text = id.ToString();
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

If Form1 is already open, it means the constructor had already run. Make a setter method and call the method from other form.

```
public void UpdateUnitAndRate(string units, string rate)
{
    ItemId_LBL.Text = units;
    ItemName_TXT.Text = rate;
}

//put it in form2 (or itemform) as a field
Form1 f1;

//add this in the method or event (in itemform) you want to update units and rates in form1
if (f1 != null)
   f1.UpdateUnitAndRate(units, rate);
else
   f1 = new Form1(units, rate);
```

Comment: tried but not worked not populated both by function and by constructor fails to populate textboxes

Comment: Form1 constructor should work on the load and fill-in the text of ItemId_LBL and ItemName_TXT. Once you confirm the Form1 constructor works, then you can go on and see if the new method also works.

Comment: constructor only works when i use f1.show() but i want to use existing open form

Comment: If you are able to do, f1.Show(), then you should also be able to do f1.UpdateUnitAndRate(units, rate); assuming f1 already is an instance of form1.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `Application.OpenForms`, use this to create an instance of the open form and access the textbox.

Comment: i am making mistake because i am creating a new object how to use previously created open form object

Comment: @office302 you need to create an instance of the other Form inside the form from which you want to access the textbox. Do not use `= new yourformname();` but use `= Application. OpenForms["yourformname"] as yourformname;`

Comment: Form f1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"]  tried even works but not getting acess to textboxes of form1

Comment: Now I get it, you need to make your textbox public or at least create a public setter.

Comment: i get i no want to call InitializeComponent();  there is any way without usig this

Comment: I never tried this but maybe if you create the form manually without the designer. Is there a particular reason you want to do not want to use this?

Comment: yes i have 2 portion in same for name party and items both are getting data from different forms onclick but need to open a new instance of form and remove data of previous instance

Comment: But that doesn't mean you can't call InitializeComponents() (afaik)